# Trouble displaying data from multiple nested tables in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, nested-attributes, partials

I'm new to rails.  I've searched and been stuck on this problem for a couple days now.

I am building a site where there are users, bands (that users can join), tours (that belong to bands), and stops (stops on the tours).  I have tables for each, as well as additional tables that link them together by id (bandmembership, bandtourmembership, tourstopmembership).

I followed a few tutorials and have used belongs_to, has_many => through to link these all together and I have used nested attributes to display data from one level deep successfully.

The final format I'm trying to display is

```
User Name
=> Band Name #1
====> Tour Name #1
========> Tour Stop #1
========> Tour Stop #2
====> Tour Name #2
========> Tour Stop #1
========> Tour Stop #2
=> Band Name #2
====> Tour Name #3
========> Tour Stop #1
========> Tour Stop #2
```

etc.

Currently I only can get the band name to display without an error, but it displays the same band name 3 times (there are 3 in the database). When I try to add in tours it just gives an error. I'd also like to try to use a partial and a collection to break out the rendering of each time of item.

**My questions are**

1. Why is the partial displaying the same name 3 times and how do I get it to display the correct name?
2. Why am I not able to access tours from bands and how do I get it to cooperate?

---

**views/users/show.html.erb**

```
<h1>Dashboard</h1>
<%= render partial: 'shared/user_item' %>
<% if @user.bands.any? %>
   <h2>You are in <%= @user.bands.count %> bands:</h2>
   <%= render partial: 'shared/band_item', collection: @band_items %>
<% else %>
```

---

**shared/_band_item.html.erb**

```
<%= @band.name %>
```

---

**shared/_tour_item.html.erb**

```
<%= @tour.name %>
```

---

**shared/_stop_item.html.erb**

```
<%= @stop.name %>
```

---

**controllers/users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "You are now signed in"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @band_items = Bandmembership.where(user_id: @user.id)
    @band = Band.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:firstname, :lastname, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end


end
```

---

**models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :bandmemberships
  has_many :bands, :through => :bandmemberships
  has_many :tours, :through => :bands

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bands, :tours

end
```

---

**models/bandmembership.rb**

```
class Bandmembership < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :band

end
```

**models/tour.rb**

```
class Tour < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :tourstopmemberships
  has_many :stops, :through => :tourstopmemberships

  has_many :bandtourmemberships
  has_many :bands, :through => :bandtourmemberships

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :stops

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This smells like something solvable by a class-level delegate method (Rails Antipatterns, pp 6-7)

You've got the show method pulling the params for both user and band. Is that something like tld.com/user/1/band/3?

If you don't have params for both in the ID, then it's pulling the user's ID for band or vice versa.

From a code perspective, you should be able to refactor towards something like this:

```
<h1>Dashboard</h1>

<%# this should render app/views/users/_user.html.erb %>
<%= render @user %>

<% if @user.bands %>
  <h2>
    You are in <%= @user.bands.count %> bands:
  </h2>
  <ul>
    <%= @user.bands.each do band %>
      <%# this should render app/views/bands/_band.html.erb %>
      <%= render @band,
                 locals: (band: band) %>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<%- end -%>
```

Your _band.html.erb would be

```
<li class="band-name">
    <%= band.name %>
</li>
```

The code may not be 100% right as I keep jumping between a 2.3 app and a 4.x app. But the principle is this:

1.) Use ActiveRecord's power to your benefit. You've got the model association, so you don't need to do the lookup yourself. @user.bands should return an array of bands the user belongs to since they belong to those bands THROUGH bandmemberships.

2.) If you need to get to something, don't walk the tree over 2 or 3 items. e.g. @user.band.first.tour.first is bad bad juju. Create a method that finds this on the User model and then go from there, e.g.

```
def next_tour
    User.tour.first etc etc
end
```

and then call it in the view as @user.next_tour or whatever.

3.) Use the power of render @collection_name and use the defaults to clean your code up. It's easier to read and better than a lot of partials floating around in shared/.

This is something I harp on a lot when I give my Rails View talks, the partials should belong in the folder for the controller they exist under. /app/views/tours/_tour.html.erb and so forth would be better than the tour_item under shared. It's the rendering of a single tour entry for anywhere in the app.

I'm not sure about tourstopmemberships as a join model either. What are you joining it to? Why not just have a tour has many stops and stops belong to a tour? If you're looking at a venue model as well, then perhaps stops is the join model between tours and venues. That then allows you to add additional meta data onto the stop

```
stop.tour
stop.venue
stop.start_time
stop.support_act (which could be a different relationship)
```

etc.

Comment: I'm trying to wrap my head around this.  I moved all my partials back into their respective views.  I never intended for the url to be tld.com/user/1/band/3, so doing @band = Band.find(params[:id]) might just be plain wrong.  My intention there was that as the view was iterating doing the each statements that it would pull each band.  On #3, The model part I don't quite understand... So are you saying I should modify each model to go one level down?  So User will get band in the model, Band will get Tour, and Tour will get Stop?  Then they can be accessed through Do, each methods?